# Snowflake Pass column names to select query - single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need to find out a way to select only those columns from a data table that are defined non-sensitive in a PII classification table.

I wrote this -

```
select (select col_name from PII_CLASSFCTN 
where TAG_VAL = 'NON-SENSITIVE') FROM TEST;
```

and got an error single-row subquery returns more than one row which makes sense but then how do I re-write this SQL?

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1):

I have to rewrite my answer. You can not do it with one simple SQL but Snowflake Scripting (the new feature) can help you. Here is a sample demonstration:

```
create table PII_CLASSFCTN (col_name varchar, TAG_VAL varchar )
as select * from values 
('A1','NON-SENSITIVE'),
('A2','NON-SENSITIVE'),
('A3','SENSITIVE');

create table TEST ( A1 varchar, A2 varchar, A3 varchar ) 
as select * from values 
('Gokhan','SQL','Master'),
('Jack','SQL','Novice');

declare
  res RESULTSET;
  col_name varchar;
  select_statement varchar;
  c1 CURSOR for select col_name from PII_CLASSFCTN where TAG_VAL = 'NON-SENSITIVE';
begin
  select_statement := 'SELECT ';
  for rs in c1 do
     select_statement := select_statement || ' ' || rs.col_name || ',';
  end for;
  select_statement := RTRIM(select_statement, ',' ) || ' FROM TEST';
  res := (execute immediate :select_statement);
  return table(res);
end;


+--------+-----+
|   A1   | A2  |
+--------+-----+
| Gokhan | SQL |
| Jack   | SQL |
+--------+-----+
```

More info about Snowflake Scripting: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html

Comment: No, I need to return all columns classification table so that those columns can then be retrieved from data table TEST.

Comment: I'm confused. Why dont you use "select col_name from PII_CLASSFCTN where TAG_VAL = 'NON-SENSITIVE' " then? What is the point of using the TEST table. Do you need to join these tables?

Comment: Now I got it ---- you want to pass the colum name!!! So I have to update my answer

Comment: @hiphop I updated my answer. Hope it helps